# Transfer data from SQL Server to PostgreSQL on Linux

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, data-transfer, dts

What is the best way to transfer the data from SQL Server database on Windows to a PostgreSQL database on Linux?

The current SQL Server database there are about 500,000 rows per table, and about 80 tables all together.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar enough with sql-server to assert this is the best way, but if you just need the data, you could try using odbc and a foreign data wrapper:

http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Foreign_data_wrappers

Comment: This is it: http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/249-ODBC-Foreign-Data-wrapper-to-query-SQL-Server-on-Window---Part-2.html